# Python httplib2 Access is denied

Tags: python, caching, oauth-2.0, httplib2

I am facing a problem on executing simple code.

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
resp, content = h.request("http://example.org/", "GET")
```

Output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1175, in __init__
    self.cache = FileCache(cache)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 700, in __init__
    os.makedirs(self.cache)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: '.cache'
```

Anyone with any suggestions to fix this error?

Comment: It looks like you cannot create the .cache directory in your working directory. Maybe switching your current directory fixs it.

Comment: Do you have permission to create folders where the script is executing?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a permissions issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working you could just leave out the cache directory:

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
resp, content = h.request("http://example.org/", "GET")
```

As the comments say above, you don't have permission to create the `.cache` directory relative to the path you're running the code from.

Of course, having a cache is better...

For a simple, in-memory cache which won't cause you permissions headaches, checkout this article I wrote: http://grahamlyons.com/article/a-simple-in-memory-cache-for-python-s-httplib2